# $T$ is normal *iff* for every vector $a$ and scalar $c$ that $Ta = ca$ we also have $T^*a = \overline{c}a$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

T is a linear operator on a finite-dimensional inner-product space. Prove that $T$ is normal *iff* for every vector $a$ and scalar $c$ that $Ta = ca$ we also have $T^*a = \overline{c}a$.

So I've done one side of the proof but I'm stuck doing the other side; assume $TT^* = T^*T$ then we have:

$
(TT^* a \mid a) = (T^*T a \mid a) \implies (T^*a \mid T^*a) = (Ta \mid Ta) \implies \|Ta\| = \|T^*a\|
$

we also have $(T - cI)^* = T^* - \overline{c}I$ which easily implies $(T - cI)$ is normal. adding these together we conclude:

$\|(T - cI)a\| = \|(T - \overline{c}I)a\|$

which concludes one side of the theorem.

Comment: Study the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and its adjoint.

Comment: @GEdgar, There was something I missed in the problem, the characteristic values must be associated with the same characteristic vectors.